# How to return 2 or 3 values with Tuple?

Tags: c#, return, tuples

So I'm making a silly game in c# but I'm a bit stuck here.

I'm trying to return either 2 values or either 3 values, depends on the rules of the game.

I need to know how I can return different amounts of values in only one function. Like sometimes I need to return 3 values and sometimes 7 values... in one function.

The error is with the variable `tuple` of course, as I can't return less than 3 values..

```
public Tuple<int, int, int> movepion(schaken.pion pion, int row, int column)
{
    int row2 = row + 1;

    //posities berekenen
    if (pion.kleur == Color.Blue)
    {
        if (pion.volgnr == 0) { row++; row2++; }
        else { row++; }
    }
    else
    {
    }

    // declaration
    var tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(row, column);
    var tuple2 = new Tuple<int, int, int>(row, row2, column);

    // what position?
    if (pion.volgnr == 0)
    {
        pion.volgnr = pion.volgnr + 1;
        return tuple2;
    }
    else
    {
        return tuple;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a summary of what this is used for? What's the tuple and tuple2 going to be used for?

Comment: @Thibaut if all values are int, have you considered returning an array, IEnumerable or list?

Comment: @sr28 i want to make kind of a chess game, so if i click a pion it will show all the different positions the pion can be placed. i need more rows or columns when there are more positions it can be placed.

Comment: @Thibaut - and is this Tuple supposed to represent the variety of options to move?

Comment: @Sascha No i didn't know about this method i'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @GiladGreen yes, the more positions the more tuples i think.. i know it's a bit messy :s

Comment: you should consider using a separate data type to represent a position on your chess board and return a List<Position> when you call for permissible moves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Return a collection instead of a `Tuple<>`

```
public IEnumerable<int> movepion(schaken.pion pion, int row, int column)
{
    IEnumerable<int> result;
    bool return2Items = false; //Some logic part to decide how many items to return
    if(return2Items)
        result = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
    else
        result = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

   return result;    
}
```

---

After the better understanding the comments I'd recommend to create an object `MoveOption` and that the function will return `IEnumerable<MoveOption>`

```
public class MoveOption
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your function:

```
public IEnumerable<MoveOption> movepion(schaken.pion pion, int row, int column)
{
    List<MoveOption> options = new List<MoveOption>();

    if(/*some condition*/)
    {
        options.Add(new MoveOption{ X = 1, Y = 2 });
    }

    if(/*some condition*/)
    {
        options.Add(new MoveOption{ X = 5, Y = 7 });
    }

    //Rest of options

    return options;
}
```

Then if you want to take it one step forward you can use inheritance and:

```
public interface IMoveOptionCalcumator
{
    public MoveOption Calculate(/*input*/);
}

public class MoveOptionX : IMoveOptionCalcumator
{
    public MoveOption Calculate(/*input*/) { /*some implementation*/ }
}
```

And in your function:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public IEnumerable<IMoveOptionCalcumator> MoveOptionCalculators { get; set; }

    public YourClass()
    {
        // Initialize the collection of calculators 
        // You can look into Dependency Injection if you want even another step forward :)
    }


    public IEnumerable<int> movepion(schaken.pion pion, int row, int column)
    {
        List<MoveOption> options = new List<MoveOption>();
        foreach (var item in MoveOptionsCalculators)
        {
            var result = item.Calculate(/*input*/);
            if(result != null)
            {
                options.Add(result);
            }
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really good, i'm going to try this and let you know if it worked!

Comment: @Thibaut - Check what I added with the interface - Might be more what you are looking for

Comment: I have this weird problem the `List` in `new List` is giving me an error, i don't know why... and i'll try the first possibility first and i'll try to make it to the next step you gave me here. you're really helping me out here!

Comment: @Thibaut - Ya :) take it step by step :) That is how one learns

Comment: @Thibaut - Thanks for the edit :) forgot to type it while trying to type as fast as possible hahaha :) And even better for solving it yourself - Good one

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the return type to

```
Tuple<int, int, int?>
```

That way you would have

```
var tuple = new Tuple<int, int, int?>(row, column, null);
```

Anyway, I think it would be best to clear the semantics of the method and probably have it return a meaningfull custom data type.

Comment: This still returns 3 values - just that 1 of them is a `null`

Comment: This didn't work, i can't convert type  `int?` to  `int` it says

Comment: use .Value to get the int from your Nullable<int>

Comment: You have to change the return type of the method and the type of tuple2 to be the same of tuple.
Anyway, it would be best to follow Geoffrey's advice, returning IEnumerable<Position> or IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>.

Comment: This also doesn't support what the question states that she might have 7 values to return